# What is Bash command or script to extract file name from a file containing multiple lines of information in the format date: filename: File status

Tags: bash

I want to extract only the filenames from a file containing multiple records in the format of:

```
date : filename: filestatus
```

For example three records from the file looks like this:

```
2021/07/17 15:08:29 INFO  : 0001 ABC-TEST1-0001A A&E.xml: Copied (new)
2021/07/17 15:08:29 INFO  : Test1-0002A Annotations.xml: Copied (new)
2021/07/17 15:10:19 INFO  : 001 ABC-72XWN-2023A;A;1;A-E;Example.jpg: Multi-thread Copied (new)
```

The bash script or commands should give me only the filename from each line. The information that I want to extract should be:

```
0001 ABC-TEST1-0001A A&E.xml
Test1-0002A Annotations.xml
001 ABC-72XWN-2023A;A;1;A-E;Example.jpg
```

Comment: Look at `sed`, that's easiest.

Answer (score 1):

Your field separation using `":"` as `FS` with `awk` will include surrounding whitespace in the extracted filenames (of course you can trim the whitespace), or simply use `sed` instead, e.g.

```
sed -E 's/^.*[[:blank:]]:[[:blank:]]([^:]+).*$/\1/' file
```

Where the substitution above captures the filename following the `[[:blank:]]:[[:blank:]]` occurrence and considers everything from that point to the next `':'` to be the filename. The first backreference `\1` is used to reinsert the filename captured with the capture group `([^:]+)`.

If the whitespace surrounding `':'` before the filename can vary, then match all whitespace surrouding the `':'` by including the `+` repetition operator around the whitespace, e.g.:

```
sed -E 's/^.*[[:blank:]]+:[[:blank:]]+([^:]+).*$/\1/' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your input in `file`:

```
$ sed -E 's/^.*[[:blank:]]:[[:blank:]]([^:]+).*$/\1/' file
0001 ABC-TEST1-0001A A&E.xml
Test1-0002A Annotations.xml
001 ABC-72XWN-2023A;A;1;A-E;Example.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest

```
 awk -F: '{print $2}' filename
```

Comment: Thanks @stark.  awk -F: '{print $4}' filename actually worked for me.